# How do I rename files if they match with names within a csv column?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working in a directory in which I have a lot (about 100) of BAM file with a specific name. In the same directory I have also a csv file containing 4 column: `FileID, File.name, Donor, Type`

Let's say that my bam files in the directory are: `Donor.1234-xyz.bam, Donor.5678-abc.bam, Donor.1011-def.bam, Donor.1213-ghi.bam` (which match with the name in the column number 2 called File.name of the csv file).

I am not really familiar with coding so I will try to explain what I would like to do.
I would like the script to rename the bam files I have in the folder with the name Donor+Type (column 3 and 4).
So if Donor.1234-xyz.bam is also found in the File.name column of the csv file then I would like it to be called with the string in column 3 and 4 (basically I would like to replace the bam name with everything in
the corresponding column of the Donor and the Type).

```
    BAM_FILE="*.bam"
    BAM=$BAM_FILE
    NAME="cat kich.csv | cut -f2 -s"
    NM=$NAME
    DONOR="cat kich.csv | cut -f3 -s"
    DO=$DONOR
    TYPE="cat kich.csv | cut -f4 -s"
    TY=$TYPE    
    for file_name in "$BAM"; 
    do
    if [[ "$file_name" == "$NM" ]] then 
    mv ${file_name} ${DO}_${TY} ;    
    done
```

But it doesn't work really, as I said I'm still naïve.
So, could you help me please to fix this problem?

Comment: You're storing commands in variables, but the commands are never executed. This is where the [3.5.4 Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) syntax is needed.

Comment: Also, in the `for` command, the glob pattern is quoted, so it won't expand to a list of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is something like that:

```
$ cat file.csv     
01;file01;part1;part2
02;file02;part3;part4
```

You can try it

```
while read -r line;
do
   file=$(echo $line | cut -d";" -f2)
   newName=$(echo $line | cut -d";" -f3)_$(echo $line | cut -d";" -f4)    

   mv $file $newName

done < file.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r id name donor type; do
    in="${name}.bam"
    ! [ -f "$in" ] && continue

    out="${donor}_${type}.bam"
    if [ -f "$out" ]; then
        echo "output exists: $out"
        continue
    fi

    echo mv -iv "$in" "$out"
done <kich.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose the directory contains

```
Donor.1011-def.bam
Donor.1234-xyz.bam
Donor.5678-abc.bam
kich.csv
```

and kich.csv contains

```
1,Donor.1234-xyz.bam,DO1,TY1
2,Donor.5678-abc.bam,DO2,TY2
3,Donor.1011-def.bam,DO3,TY3
4,Donor.1213-ghi.bam,DO4,TY4
```

(note that the csv file contains **more** than what's in the directory)

I would not loop over the files, I'd loop over the contents of the csv file:

```sh
while IFS=, read -r id filename donor type; do
    if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then
        echo mv "$filename" "${donor}_${type}"
    fi
done < kich.csv
```

which outputs

```
mv Donor.1234-xyz.bam DO1_TY1
mv Donor.5678-abc.bam DO2_TY2
mv Donor.1011-def.bam DO3_TY3
```

That loop is:

- reading lines from the csv file (`< kich.csv`);
- splitting them into comma-separated fields (`IFS=, read -r id filename donor type`)
- checking to see if the filename listed in the csv file exists (`[[ -f "$filename" ]]`)
- then emitting the mv command.

If you're happy with that output, remove the `echo` to actually rename the files.

Comment: Very well explained!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{print "[ -f \""$2"\" ] && mv \""$2"\" \""$3"_"$4"\""}' kich.csv | sh
```